# Change in static library used by other static library

Tags: c++, c, linker

I have 2 library files, lib1.a and lib2.a in my project. Lib1.a is using lib2.a . I have given source code of lib2.a but I don't have source code of lib1.a. For my project I changed lib2.a lets say I add a local variable inside a function.

My question, function names didn't changed, do I need to recompile lib1.a with changed lib2.a ?
Is there anyway I tell to linker "lib1.a should use new lib2.a" without source code of lib1.a ?

Comment: Were the libraries originally compiled by a C or C++ compiler?

Comment: Libraries build with C compiler

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's just something like an added local variable as you say, there should be no need to rebuild the other library.  This is because static libraries don't typically link each other directly, but rather the executable eventually links them all together.

Comment: To expand on this a little bit: lib1.a will try to point to a location in memory that the lib2.a function is stored in. The problem though, is that since the lib2.a function isn't in the same file as lib1.a, lib1.a won't know where that function is. The linker's job is to "resolve" these addresses. So the linker will know to combine these files since one depends on the other.

Comment: Now if you create a whole new function in lib2.a, lib1.a won't know about that new function because it does not use it. However, you can modify a function however you want, as long as the prototype is not changed, and lib1.a will still be able to use it because it is only referring to addresses.