# How do static .lib files link each other?

Tags: c++, c

For example, if I have a `lib A` that has dependency on `lib B`, then do I need to link both `lib A` and `lib B` or only `lib A`, when I write a program `C` that depends on `lib A`?

Comment: This might be usefull http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15973153/change-in-static-library-used-by-other-static-library

Comment: A thing to note is that you can have (and you shouldn't!) circular dependencies between libs. As they are all put into one exe (big blob) this isn't a problem for "linker" (apart from some tricks that you have to do when compiling under Linux). So keep in mind that compilation system won't protect you from such issues.

Answer (score 5):

Static libraries are not linked. Notice that the tool creating a static library is not a linker—it's `ar` (archiver) on Unix-like platforms and `lib` (librarian) when using the MS toolchain. This is an important point to remember when dealing with static libraries and linking.

And it should answer your question. Unless the author of `A` took explicit extra steps to put the *contents* of `B` into `A`, you'll need to link against both `A` and `B`.

Answer (score 1):

A library (A) that needs another library (B) will link that library to the exe. This is because A doesnt need to know the code in B, only the exe does. This is because in the linking stage, all code in the libraries are effectively copied into the exe, therefore all references to B from A will be resolved at that step.